# The procedure entry point CryptStringToBinaryW could not be located in the dynamic link library CRYPT32.dll

Tags: hardware, dvd

Can't install DVD-RW drive. An error occurs:

> The procedure entry point CryptStringToBinaryW could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library CRYPT32.dll"

How to manage it on Windows 2000 SP4?

Surfing the web found only this
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread146113.html
and this
http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/2003-11/0556.html
Installing kiwee_toolbar_installer.exe really produces this error.
Also using new usb devices cause it happen.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's documentation for [CryptStringToBinary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380285(VS.85).aspx), the minimum operating system requirements are:

```
Client: Windows XP
Server: Windows Server 2003
```

So, basically you can't use those drivers on Win2K SP4.

Answer (score 0):

CryptStringToBinary is supported on Windows XP on up, not Windows 2000.  Software that requires this function will not run on Windows 2000 SP4.  There is no workaround.  You need to contact the creators of the app to ask for Windows 2000 support.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, thank you. One more reason for upgrade to newer Windows versions :)
Or may be just do sfc /scannow and overtake this DLL-hell?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've manage to get rid of this error message and my DVD-RW was installed flawlessly after that :) Step by step:

1) sfc /scannow restored some files but this doesn't help

2) when looking for devices in Device Manager window Process Monitor by Mark Russinovich revealed this:

2130    14:00:47,6636859    System  8   RegQueryKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ElbyDelay    BUFFER TOO SMALL    Query: Basic, Length: 0

2131    14:00:47,6638242    System  8   RegQueryKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ElbyDelay    BUFFER TOO SMALL    Query: Basic, Length: 0

2132    14:00:47,7063290    System  8   IRP_MJ_CREATE   C:\WINNT\system32\drivers\ElbyDelay.sys NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Execute/Traverse, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a

2133    14:00:47,7067271    System  8   IRP_MJ_CREATE   C:\WINNT\system32\drivers\ElbyDelay.sys NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a

I remembered that some time ago beta version of Virtual Clone Drive was uninstalled.

3) lastly I've delete occurences for "ElBy" using Device Manager (show hidden devices) and regedit.